# Is Tableau Desktop a Thick Client or is it a Thin Client

Tags: tableau-api

Is Tableau Desktop a Thick Client or is it a Thin Client? In case, it is a thin client, where is the server (mentioning thin client server, not tableau server)?

Comment: Tableau Desktop is a complete app that runs entirely on your local machine. It references external *data* but describing it as a client isn't useful terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Desktop runs entirely on your local machine. When you open a workbook from Tableau Server, it downloads the workbook completely and creates a local copy of the extracted data on your machine. This is why Desktop makes you put the database passwords in again every time you open a workbook from Tableau Server- it's recreating the extracts/reestablishing the live connections.

When you publish to Server/Online, you upload the workbook and data sources to Tableau Server. It copies your workbook and datasources and works independent of your Tableau Desktop installation from there.